# Sqlite3 database in Node/Express - all values null, do I need to import it?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sqlite, express

My code is as follows in server.js:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const dbfile = "./db/us-census.db";
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbfile);

db.serialize(function () {
  db.each("SELECT * FROM census_learn_sql LIMIT 1", function (err, row) {
    console.log(row);
  });
});

db.close();
```

The output I'm receiving is:

```
{ age: null,
  'class of worker': null,
  'industry code': null,
  'occupation code': null,
  education: null,
  'wage per hour': null,
  'last education': null,
  'marital status': null,
  'major industry code': null,
  'major occupation code': null
}
```

I tried looking at the db file using DB Browser for SQLite, and I can see the structure of the database like this:

[image: screenshot from DB Browser for SQLite]

I'm rather inexperienced with SQL databases, so I'm not sure if theres a step I need to take in order to import the SQLite database prior to use. Also, I can't see any indexing on the single table, so it give me even more reason to believe I'm missing a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to ascertain that there is data in the table, its just that the first 2000 or so records are NULL.